# How are baggage fees calculated on multi-city trips with the same airline

Tags: luggage, fees-and-charges

I've booked a multi city trip consisting out of 7 flights of which 2 are directly connected (90 minute and 4 hour layover). How many times would I have to pay the bagage fees?

The first and final flight are international (to Europe) and the rest are US domestic if that matters.

Comment: How many tickets? All tickets was emitted by the same company?

Comment: It's on one ticket/trip.

Answer (score 2):

If you are subject to baggage fees, meaning:

- They are not included in the fare
- You are not an elite program member
- Are not traveling in a premium cabin
- You do not get free bag because of some other benefit, such as a credit card

Fees are *typically* collected per Origin-Destination city pair, regardless of how many connections are involved.

For example, if you going from JFK to LAX, you pay $15 to check a bag if you fly JFK-LAX direct or connect JFK-DFW-LAX.  You do not pay $15 for each flight on a connection.

If you have 7 flights and only two are connected, you will pay the fee 6 times because you have 6 O/D trips.

Comment: And the international flights (and any connecting domestic legs that go with those international flights) may have different baggage policies, such as having the first bag free. The exact policy would depend on the airline and the destination.